# Beamer sty doesn't modify toc

Tags: beamer, bullets

I half-wrote half-copied a sty file for my beamer slide. When I tried to use the commands

```
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[square unnumbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[circle numbered]
```

It doesn't modify the pdf file (shown below). How do I actually add those bullets and color them as the same red used for section names? Much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Please make a compilable minimal working example - without seeing the code of your theme, we would need a crystal ball to solve this ...